# Lavalier for video production

Tags: microphone, video

Looking for a Lavalier microphone for video production. The Rode Lavalier Mic looks like the best bang for buck in regards to quality for price. But really for my current budget the many times cheaper Audio Technica ATR3350 Lavalier Microphone is a serious contender for my $$.

I'm thinking of making do with either straight into the camera (the long cable that comes with the AT makes it perfect for this) or into a (currently unpurchased) Zoom H1 for the portability.

Does anyone have any experience with these mics? Any comments or suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Added that lavalier tag for you!

Comment: What did you think of the Giant Squid lav? Did you get the omnidirectionnal mono lav?

Answer (score 1):

I got an email from Darren at Giant Squid saying that it should work fine straight into a Zoom H1.

My current camera is a Sanyo HD2000. It looks like it's got 'plug-in power' (Microphone input (plug-in power type: φ2.5mm,φ3.5mm adaptor bundled). So it looks good to work without the ($60) battery pack if I went with the Giant Squid.

Any other suggestions as to which entry level lav to get for video? What was your experience with the Giant Squid - would you use it again for the same or different purpose?

Source: http://sanyo.com/xacti/english/products/vpc_hd2000/spec.html

Comment: I've ordered the Giant Squid lav.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across these Giant Squid mics that look interesting (http://www.giant-squid-audio-lab.com). I like this guy's philosophy. If he mics are at least as good as Audio Technica's I'll be happy.

Anyone tried out his mics and got any comments?

Comment: I have used the Giant Squid mics, but they are electrets need 5V biasing voltage (also called "Plug-in power") .. So you will need to check with your camera if they support that or need a battery pack in the middle.. I believe the H1 should support it..